# Can't open a separate usbdrive when booting from a liveusb install 12.10

Tags: 12.10, live-usb

My problem is using a separate flash drive when running from my live usb of ubuntu 12.10. The problem is that when I choose to `Try Ubuntu from this usb drive` it no longer lets me access my other flash drive. It automatically sets it to part of the live usb but it's a completely separate flash drive.
Ubuntu loads fine and everything but when I go to access my other flash drive nothing happens. When I try to open it from the home folder it gives me 
`Unable to mount 3.5 volume` 
Adding `read ACL for uid 999` to `media/ubuntu` failed: `Operation not supported` message. 
My live usb is on a 8gb flash drive and my other flash drive is 4g.

Answer (score 4):

There was change for 12.10 where the mount point for automount devices is now in /media/username.  Previously the mount point was in /media.  I'm not sure why they changed it, but it seems like that the creation for /media/username at boot time was forgotten for the LiveUSB/DVD.

Try making the directory and see if the automount now works:

```
sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu
```

If that doesn't work, try mounting manually:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

...assuming the device you are trying to mount is /dev/sdc.  The mount point will be /mnt, or you can use /media/ubuntu if you wish since you just made it.

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed in the current Ubuntu version. The bug was that they forgot to create a user under media and create the appropriate permissions. Hope this helps.

The bug and its explanation can be found here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059

substitute USERNAME with ubuntu or any name of your choice, as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /media/USERNAME
sudo chown USERNAME.USERNAME /media/USERNAME
```

or

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER
sudo chown $USER.$USER /media/$USER
```

Answer (score 0):

That was Exactly what I needed to know!!!  Thanks

There was change for 12.10 where the mount point for automount devices is now in `/media/username`. Previously the mount point was in `/media`. I'm not sure why they changed it, but it seems like that the creation for `/media/username` at boot time was forgotten for the LiveUSB/DVD.

Try making the directory and see if the automount now works:

`sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu`

If that doesn't work, try mounting manually:

`sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`

...assuming the device you are trying to mount is `/dev/sdc`. The mount point will be `/mnt`, or you can use `/media/ubuntu` if you wish since you just made it.

I used that info to create the missing DIR which then allowed me to mount the SD card and other drives I have been trying to mount but getting that same error.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occours in lubuntu 12.10 booting from live USB.
Creating the directory /media/lubuntu solves the problem.

```
sudo mkdir /media/lubuntu
```