# After upgrading to 12.10 usb drives fail to mount

Tags: 12.10, usb-drive, version-upgrade

Following upgrade to 12.10, my usb drives - both pen drives and a usb hard drive - fail to mount with the error message:
`Unable to mount *name of drive* volume
Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to '/media/*my home file name*' failed: Operation not supported`

This is on a desktop Dell Inspiron 530.

I also have a Dell Inspiron Mini 10 netbook which I also upgraded to 12.10 (slightly smaller installation on a flash hard drive). all devices mount automatically without problems on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:
(Its from another thread [Can't open a separate usbdrive when booting from a liveusb install 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215219/cant-open-a-separate-usbdrive-when-booting-from-a-liveusb-install-12-10))

---

Things have changed in the current ubuntu . The BUG was they forgot to create a user under media and create permission . Hope this helps

The BUG and explanation can be found at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059

substitute USERNAME with ubuntu or any name of your choice

```
sudo mkdir /media/USERNAME

sudo chown USERNAME.USERNAME /media/USERNAME
```

or

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER

sudo chown $USER.$USER /media/$USER
```

Answer (score 0):

After I purchased a new computer I needed to get my thumb drives working on it.  Here's the procedure:

1) Open "Disk Utility", and look for your device, and click on it.  This will let you be sure you know the correct filesystem type and device name for it.  In my case, it was 'ext4' and '/dev/sdb1' respectively.  Next: Decide what you want to call your thumb drive.  I called mine 'USB16-C', but you choose your own name. Before closing Disk Utility, click unmount.

Then run steps 2 to 4 in a terminal window.

2) `sudo mkdir -p /media/USB16-C`

3) `sudo mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/sdb1 /media/USB16-C`

4) `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/USB16-C`

Now my thumb drive is accessible, and it automatically connects when I reboot too.